Sequence $f(k)=\underbrace{\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\cdots}}}}_{\text{$k\ m$'s}}-\underbrace{\sqrt{m-\sqrt{m-\sqrt{m-\cdots}}}}_{\text{$k\ m$'s}}$

Define $$f(k)=\underbrace{\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\cdots}}}}_{\text{$k$
$m$'s}}-\underbrace{\sqrt{m-\sqrt{m-\sqrt{m-\cdots}}}}_{\text{$k$
$m$'s}}$$
Given $m$ and $k$ are integers such that $m\ge1$ and $k\ge2$, then
prove that:
$1)$ $f(k)\ge1$ if $k$ is even
$2)$ $f(k)\le1$ if $k$ is odd
$3)$ $f(k)\to1$ as $k\to\infty$
$4)$ if $k$ is fixed then $f(k)\to1$ as $m\to\infty$.

Note that in the $3$rd part, $k$ is increased by $2$ like $k=3$, then $k=5$ then $k=7$, and so on (if started with an odd number, then it approaches $1$ from below), or $k=2$, then $k=4$, then $k=6$ then $k=8$ and so on(if started with an even numbers, then it approaches $1$ from above).
In the $4$th part I mean: say if $k=3$ means the expression is $\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m}}}-\sqrt{m-\sqrt{m-\sqrt{m}}}$ so if we keep increasing $m$ it will approach 1. And if $k$ is even then it approaches $1$ from above, while if $k$ is odd it will approach $1$ from below.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the somewhat related (e.g., for the third part of your question) Proving $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a.....}}}}-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a....}}}}=1$.

are you sure that $f(k) \ge 1$ when $k$ is even? A quick computation for $m=4, k=4$ gave me $f(k) <1$; the rest of the points are quite easy to prove but this one seems not to be true though of course my computation may have been in error;

@Conrad yeah I am sure it's >=1(for m=4,k=4 I checked on calculator and it is indeed>1) and is  equal to 1 at approaching infinity

@Conrad if you feel you have any progress on rest of the parts except 3rd do let me know and really thanks for your time

figured out $f(2k) \ge 1$ and posted full answer

@Conrad I like your approach and I guess all answers are correct. Thanks for your time

Happy to be of help - as noted everything but $f(2k)\ge 1$ is fairly straightforward but the latter is a bit trickier

Consider $A(k,m)=A(k), k \ge 1$ the first term with all pluses where we omit the dependence on $m$ when fixed and $B(k,m)=B(k), k \ge 1$ the second term with the alternating minuses. We clearly have $$A(k+1)^2=A(k)+m, A(1)=\sqrt m$$ $$B(k+1)^2=m-B(k), B(1)=\sqrt m$$
$A(k)$ is increasing and bounded by $\sqrt {2m}$ by an easy induction since $m \ge2$ so (by taking the limit in the recurrence and noting that it is positive) $$A(k) \to \frac{\sqrt {4m+1}+1}{2}, A(k) \le \frac{\sqrt {4m+1}+1}{2} $$
Similarly $B(k)$ alternates in size (clear from its form or easy induction if you wish) so $$B(1) \ge B(3) \ge...B(2k+1) \ge ... \ge B(2k) \ge B(2k-2) \ge...B(2)$$
If $q_1=\lim_{n \to \infty}B(2n), q_2=\lim_{n \to \infty}B(2n+1)$ (exist by the above) we get $0< q_1 \le q_2, q_1^2=m-q_2, q_2^2=m-q_1$ so $(q_2-q_1)(q_1+q_2)=q_2-q_1$.
Since $q_2^2+q_2 \ge q_2^2+q_1=m \ge 2$ we must have $q_2>1$ hence $q_1+q_2>1$ hence $q_1=q_2=\frac{\sqrt {4m+1}-1}{2}$
Also $B(2n) \le \frac{\sqrt {4m+1}-1}{2}, B(2n+1) \ge \frac{\sqrt {4m+1}-1}{2}$ so in particular we get $$f(2n+1)=A(2n+1)-B(2n+1) \le \frac{\sqrt {4m+1}+1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt {4m+1}-1}{2}=1$$
Since $f(k)=A(k)-B(k)$ and $A(k+1)^2-B(k+1)^2=A(k)+B(k)$ we get $$f(k)=\frac{A(k-1)+B(k-1)}{A(k)+B(k)}, k \ge 2$$ Hence $f(k)=\frac{A(k-1)+B(k-1)}{A(k)+B(k)} \to 1,  k \to \infty$ as numerator and denominator tend to same positive limit
Now $A(1)+B(1)=2\sqrt m \ge A(2)+B(2)$ (easily seen by squaring) so $f(2) \ge 1$ and we use induction to prove $f(2k+2) \ge 1$ given $f(2k) \ge 1$ or equivalently $A(2k+1) +B(2k+1) \ge A(2k+2)+B(2k+2)$ given $A(2k-1) +B(2k-1) \ge A(2k)+B(2k)$
But $A(2k+2)-A(2k+1)=\frac{A^2(2k+2)-A^2(2k+1)}{A(2k+2)+A(2k+1)}=\frac{A(2k+1)-A(2k)}{A(2k+2)+A(2k+1)}=\frac{A(2k)-A(2k-1)}{(A(2k+2)+A(2k+1))(A(2k+1)+A(2k))}$
Similarly $B(2k+1)-B(2k+2)=\frac{B(2k+1)-B(2k)}{B(2k+2)+B(2k+1)}=\frac{B(2k-1)-B(2k)}{(B(2k+2)+B(2k+1))(B(2k+1)+B(2k))}$ and since by the induction hypothesis $A(2k)-A(2k-1) \le B(2k-1)-B(2k)$ while clearly $\frac{1}{(A(2k+2)+A(2k+1))(A(2k+1)+A(2k))} \le \frac{1}{(B(2k+2)+B(2k+1))(B(2k+1)+B(2k))}$ as $A(k) \ge B(k)$ for all $k$ we get $A(2k+2)-A(2k+1) \le B(2k+1)-B(2k+2)$ hence indeed $f(2k+2) \ge 1$
So points $1,2,3$ are done and it remains to deal with point $4$
We have $2\sqrt m -2 \le A(2)+B(2) \le A(k)+B(k) \le \frac{\sqrt {4m+1}+1}{2}+\sqrt m$ (since $A(k)$ increases while $B(2)$ is the smallest of the $B$ and $B(1)=\sqrt m$ is the largest and the first inequality easily follows by squaring) so using $f(k)=\frac{A(k-1)+B(k-1)}{A(k)+B(k)}$ and the above the fact that with $k$ fixed we have $f(k,m) \to 1, m \to \infty$ follows by the squeeze theorem as the ratio between the ends goes to $1$ as $m \to \infty$
